# setNeedsDisplay on uiimageview doesn't refresh the view immediately

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I'm using AVCaptureSession to capture an image and then send it to my server.

```
[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        if (imageSampleBuffer != NULL) {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
            self.videoImageData = [imageData copy];
            [self processImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

            NSString* response=[self uploadImage];
            [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
            self.takePictureBtn.enabled = YES;
            [self setUserMessage:response];
        }
    }];

- (void) processImage:(UIImage *)image
{
...

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    int degrees = [self rotationDegrees];
    CGFloat radians =degrees * M_PI / 180.0;
    self.captureImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.captureImageView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

`- (NSString*)uploadImage` send the photo to the server

The behavior I'm expecting is after processImage terminates that the image will be displayed in the UIImageView `captureImageView` on it the activity indicator rotates but instead i get a white blanc view with the indicator rotating and only after the server post request terminates `captureImageView` displays the image

How can I achieve my desired behavior?

***Another problem*** I'm facing is that my imageSampleBuffer returns a mirror image of the taken one (object on the left appears on the right)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> This method makes
>   a note of the request and returns immediately. The view is not
>   actually redrawn until the next drawing cycle, at which point all
>   invalidated views are updated.

Since you’re doing other stuff after you call `setNeedsDisplay` the event doesn’t end and you don’t get a display immediately.

If you want to do more stuff, one approach would be to schedule the rest of the stuff in a new block, like, with

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSString *const response = [self uploadImage];
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    self.takePictureBtn.enabled = YES;
    [self setUserMessage:response];
}];
```

Comment: what do i need to change addBlockWithOperation with cause i'm getting an error: No known instance method for selector 'addBlockWithOperation:'? newbie in distress :(

Comment: You need to move the code after the call to -processImage to the end of the event, so the display gets a chance to run. I got the method name wrong, but my answer is corrected now. You could do it directly with dispatch_async(), too.